# Introductory Clause and Subject Agreement

Tags: syntactic-analysis, word-order

I am unsure whether the following sentence reads correctly with the given introductory clause.

"In addition to embodying my interests, I am confident that this program will provide me with extensive opportunities in the medical field."

Am I correctly stating that the program is the subject "embodying my interests?"
Or am I incorrectly saying that I am the subject embodying my interests.

Comment: I believe this is an offshoot of the dangling modifier (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier). I think both "I" and "this program" can be read as the subject of "embodying my interests", but the latter reading is far more easily accessed.

Comment: Why not move it to medial position? "I am confident that this program will (in addition to embodying my interests) provide me with extensive opportunities in the medical field."

Comment: You are wrong, I’m afraid. The subject of the sentence is “I”. The expression “In addition to embodying my interests” is merely a supplementary adjunct, a loosely attached expression that is not integrated into clause structure but only loosely attached - set apart by punctuation and a slight pause in speech. The supplementary adjunct is a clause but, like most non-finite clauses, it does not have an overt subject, though it is clear from the main clause that it can only be "this program".

Comment: BillJ, what happens when that is boiled down to "This program will provide me with (stuff)", please?

Then is the subject “me”?